# Change name of Laravel's created_at and updated_at

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

Can I map Laravel's timestamps from:

`created_at` to `post_date` and `post_date_gmt`?

`updated_at` to `post_modified` and `post_modified_gmt`?

---

I'm migrating a Wordpress application to Laravel.

I'm accessing a copy of the Wordpress database using Laravel.  The live version of the database is still in use so I don't want to change the schema.

The Posts table has `post_date`, `post_date_gmt`, `post_modified` and `post_modified_gmt`, but Laravel is expecting `created_at` and `updated_at`.

Is there anyway to change the column names that Laravel looks for?

I'd like Laravel to update the timestamps of all the columns that are already there.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

The accepted answer may cause problems with updating timestamps unfortunately.

You'd better override consts on your model:

```
const CREATED_AT = 'post_date';
const UPDATED_AT = 'post_modified';
```

then methods `getCreatedAtColumn` and `getUpdatedAtColumn` will return `post_date` and `post_modified` respectively, but won't do any harm.

For the other columns you need use events like @Oni suggested.

Comment: Can you explain how the accepted answer may cause problems? I'm intrigued.

Comment: Eloquent Model class refers to `static::CREATED_AT` and `static::UPDATED_AT` in some methods, also in that particular 2 that @Oni overrides. So hardcoding the columns in those methods would make Eloquent search for `created_at` and `updated_at` anyway when updating timestamps (`updateTimestamps` method for example). The same goes for `DELETED_AT` when soft deletes are used.

Comment: Hmm that seems like a possible bug in Laravel (in that it should be using the methods not the constants), right?

Comment: Definitely! At least big inconsistency, but there are more in Eloquent. Still it's by far the easiest ORM to learn and really functional component of the framework.

Comment: At least that's what that comes into my mind (overriding methods instead of constants) when I try to whip up the code example. But, it does come with a consequence of having unexpected behaviour. Overriding constants somewhat felt like a hack to me but it does get the job done. :D

Comment: If you override the consts, does that only affect the model that you set them in, or does it override the model it extends as well, therefore affecting all models?

Comment: Of course only the model you set them in AND all that inherit from it, but not parent class - `Eloquent\Model`.

Comment: on every GET output it gives json object of timestamp instead of just date

Comment: @zeetit irrelevant, change what you're returning from your HTTP method.

Answer (score 30):

If you look into the source of the `Eloquent` class

https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/4.2/Eloquent/Model.php#L223-L235

You should be able to change these column names pretty easily by overriding those constants.

```
<?php

class YourModel extends Eloquent {

    /**
     * The name of the "created at" column.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    const CREATED_AT = 'post_date';

    /**
     * The name of the "updated at" column.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    const UPDATED_AT = 'post_modified';

}
```

As for the `_gmt` version of those timestamps, you might want to look into `events`. Here is a good start

http://driesvints.com/blog/using-laravel-4-model-events

Comment: Check my answer as this is going to lead to unexpected behaviour.

Comment: I've looked into the source again and it's as what deczo said, the code that I provide will result in error when it comes to other methods that use the static constants.  I've updated the code example to reflect deczo's suggestion.

Comment: And for laravel9: https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/9.x/Eloquent/Model.php#L189

Comment: Beware! class YourModel extends Model, not Eloquent.

Answer (score 3):

Just put this in your tables model file,

```
 const CREATED_AT = 'your_custom_created_at_field_name';
 const UPDATED_AT = 'your_custom_updated_at_field_name';
```

My model looks like this for avoiding confusions

```
class diarymodule extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'diarymodule';
    const CREATED_AT = 'CreatedDate';
    const UPDATED_AT = 'UpdatedDate';
}
```

Comment: how is this answer different from the accepted answer?

Answer (score -1):

You could try using the attribute getters and getters:

```
class Post extends Eloquent
{
    public function getCreatedAtAttribute()
    {
        return $this->attributes['post_date'];
    }

    public function setCreatedAtAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['post_date'] = $value;

        // this may not work, depends if it's a Carbon instance, and may also break the above - you may have to clone the instance
        $this->attributes['post_date_gmt'] = $value->setTimezone('UTC');
    }
}
```

I don't know if this will work, but you could give it a go. Certainly a base to go on maybe - you'll have to play around with it.

Comment: Oh ignore this, Oni's is much better!

Comment: This is not the exact solutions.. Laravel is already providing the const for the timestamp fields. @jarek-tkaczyk has given proper solutions