# Laravel: Change the timestamps' names in the database

Tags: laravel, sql-timestamp

I'm trying to rename the timestamps columns (`created_at` and `updated_at`) of the `user` table in my database. I have already seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24404474/change-name-of-laravels-created-at-and-updated-at) but when I override the `CREATED_AT` and `UPDATED_AD` constants like that:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    const CREATED_AT = 'user_creation_date';
    const UPDATED_AT = 'user_update_date';
    ...
}
```

all it does is rename the properties of the `User` model, i.e. `$user->user_creation_date` and `$user->user_update_date`. The database columns remain unchanged. How should I do to rename the columns of my database while keeping the auto-update feature?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Pragmatic question: why would you want this? a `created_at` stamp on your `user` is pretty obvious in indicating that a User record was created at that time. Keeping those column names consistent in all your tables also allows for easier querying later on.

Comment: That's just more convenient when doing junctures in SQL queries, instead of doing `table1.updated_at = table2.updated_at` you just do `table1_update_date = table2_update_date`.

Comment: That's literally 1 character difference, right? Anyway, alistaircol's answer is probably the best one.

Comment: Yes I will test it. As of what you said, that's not a matter of characters difference, but a matter of handling by the framework. It's way easier to do a `->where('table1_column','table2_column')` than a `DB::raw('table1.column = table2.column')`. I don't choose what my boss tells me to do.

Comment: `DB::table('table1')->join('table2', 'table1.created_at', '=', 'table2_created_at')->select('*')->get()`? (Or a left join: `DB::table('table1')->leftJoin('table2', 'table1.created_at', '=', 'table2_created_at')->get()`)  Not trying to get in the way, you probably have good reasons! I'm just having a hard time to see what exactly the gain is of solving your question ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to update your users table migration file in `database/migrations`, it will be a file like `2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php`.

You likely have `$table->timestamps();` in the `Schema::create` call.

Looking at the code for `timestamp()` in `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.php` it reveals:

> ```
> public function timestamps($precision = 0)
> {
>     $this->timestamp('created_at', $precision)->nullable();
>
>     $this->timestamp('updated_at', $precision)->nullable();
> }
> ```

So:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
  // ..
  $table->timestamps();
});
```

Remove the call to `$table->timestamps();` and add add the two columns you want to call the timestamps:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
  // ..
  $this->timestamp('user_creation_date', 0)->nullable();
  $this->timestamp('user_update_date', 0)->nullable();
});
```

You will need to run migration again, make sure you back up data as this will drop table and recreate them.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Does it keep the auto-update feature for the update column?

Comment: I would guess so if you have the constants defined in your model like in your question.

Comment: I'll test it, I tell you later.

Answer (score 2):

You can use get attributes, e.g.

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $timestamps = true;
    protected $hidden = ['created_at', 'updated_at']; 
    protected $appends = ['user_creation_date', 'user_update_date']; 
    public function getUserCreationDateAttribute(){
        return $this->created_at; 
    }
    public function getUserUpdateDateAttribute(){
        return $this->updated_at; 
    }
}
```

Now you will get both of the columns `created_at` and `updated_at` data in the fields `user_creation_date` and `user_update_date`. The fields `created_at` and `updated_at` will stay hidden when you return `array` or `json` response or convert `object` to `array` or `json`.

Comment: But what if I want to retrieve the timestamps in my JSON ;(

Comment: You can remove it from $hidden, it will return you all four columns.

Comment: And what will be the JSON property? `updated_at` or `user_update_date`?

Comment: You will get both, ```updated_at``` and ```user_update_date``` as well as ```created_at``` and ```user_creation_date```, the fields set in ```$hidden``` will not be visible in JSON.