# Laravel - Referencing new created_at column

Tags: php, laravel

So I'm importing a Sequelize/Postgres database into a brand new Laravel app. Thing is, its columns are all weird. It uses `createdAt` and `updatedAt` when Laravel, of course, is `created_at` and `updated_at`.

Without needing to update the column names, is there a way I can reference `created_at` as the column name `createdAt`? I know you can reference table names with new names such as `public $table = 'newTableName';`

Comment: it seems there are different ways to configure naming https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/why-are-created-at-and-updated-at-constants-in-the-eloquent-model-class

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change name of Laravel's created\_at and updated\_at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24404474/change-name-of-laravels-created-at-and-updated-at)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "If you need to customize the names of the columns used to store the timestamps, you may set the CREATED_AT and UPDATED_AT constants in your model:"

```
class Flight extends Model
{
    const CREATED_AT = 'creation_date';
    const UPDATED_AT = 'last_update';
}
```

[Laravel Docs - 5.6 - Eloquent - Model Conventions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions)

Comment: Yep. Read that minute after I posted -- thanks anyway! Must have missed it