# Change name column 'created_at' and 'updated_at' in user table in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel-8

Hello I'm new in code and I try to change the name columun of created_at and updated_at in User table.

I see other tuto and he write in model :
[Change name of Laravel's created_at and updated_at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24404474/change-name-of-laravels-created-at-and-updated-at)

```
const CREATED_AT = 'post_date';
const UPDATED_AT = 'post_modified';
```

But for me in User model I write :

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Uuid;
    use HasApiTokens,HasFactory, Notifiable;

    const CREATED_AT = 'registered_on';
    const UPDATED_AT = 'modify_on';
}
```

But when I try the migration the column 'created_at' is here and no the 'registered_on'.
Any ideas ?

Comment: That just modifies the name for the Eloquent model, not the actual database or migration. The migration creates those two columns when you use [`->timestamps()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#column-method-timestamps). You can eliminate that and create your own.

Answer (score 3):

you have just changed the model's column name.

you have to change the migrations too:

remove the `->timestamps()` and add the `registered_on` & `modify_on` column, like below:

```
$table->timestamp('registered_on');
$table->timestamp('modify_on');
```

**Note**: to remove function is `timestamps()` with `s`

Then run:

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
```

to rebuild all of the tables

Comment: How ok thank you I'm noob, I write timestampsS and no timetamp, thank  a lot !

Comment: @TikkaMasala : if my answer has solved your problem, you can accept it. thanks